# referencing variable in selenium function

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I want to scroll down the page with selenium and python in an loop.

`browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 40)")`

^ this works so far.

but how can I reference a variable which will increase with every iteration?

e.g.

```
def scroll():
    global xx
    xx = 10
    while True:
         browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, xx)")
         xx += 10`
```

I can see the problem.. the input (window.scrollTo(0, xx)) is a string.

but I dont know how to fix it. Do I need to change the executed script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use one of the string interpolation options, for example:

```
def scroll():
    xx = 10
    while True:
        browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {})".format(xx))
        xx += 10
```